# SQL Server is not importing all my data from a csv file

Tags: sql-server, csv, import

I begin by saying that I have installed SQL Server Express Advance 2014. I want to import data to SQL Server from a csv file. To do this, I select a database, select Tasks, select Import Data. Then, for the Data Source I select Flat File. For the destination I choose SQL Server Native Client 11.0. For the destination table I choose the one that is autogenerated by SQL Server Import and Export Wizard, i.e., I have not created the table prior to the importation of the data, it is created while I'm in this window. The import of data finishes with a message that says that the rows has been transferred: 43 157 rows have been transferred (the total number of rows in my csv file).

In a query, when I write 'select all from this table', in the Results, I effectively see a table that contains 43 157 rows. However, not all my data has been copied. I realized this because I compared the firsts and the lasts rows of my csv file with that of the table that appeared in the section of Results. There is no problem with the first rows, at least with the the first 100 rows. But the last row, the 43 157th row that appear in the table of SQL is the 40 475th row in the csv file. So, this table in SQL has the same number of rows that that of the origin source, it does not contain all the data, though.

I repeated this process of import data, to see whether, in another new table (also autogenerated) this time all the data would be copy. It didn't happen, but in this table appeared 826 rows more than in the previos one. I mean, the 43157th row in the SQL table now coincided with the 41 301th row in the csv file. I repeated the process and again it appeared 826 rows more than in the previous table. I had a pattern!, I thougth. So I continued in this way until all the data had been copied. In effect, in the nth attempt, the last row in the nth table in SQL coincided with the last row in the csv file. But until this point, I had  entirely focus my attention of what happen in the lasts rows, and what I had not noticed is that now my firsts rows were wrong! For example, the first row in my last table in SQL, was the 2479th row in my csv file. What's going on here?

As you can notice, I'm very new in SQL Server, so I hope the explanations would not be very aggressive for a beginner. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Omg! I've been trying to figure out what was going on for almost a week. Thank you, it never occured to me that the rows would be disordered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are relying too heavily on the following assumptions:

1. That SQL Server will insert rows exactly as they ordered in the CSV file
2. That SQL Server will return rows in the order they were inserted

In general, a table is an unordered bag of rows, and you should always think about it that way, regardless of how you populated those rows. Instead of trying to match "first" and "last" rows of a source file to the destination table, match on the actual data in those rows. If the last row in your CSV file contains an e-mail address `foo@bar.com`, don't check that `foo@bar.com` is in the "last" row resulting from `SELECT * FROM dbo.table;`, check that *there exists a row* where the e-mail address is `foo@bar.com`. That it isn't the "last" row in the table doesn't mean there is a problem.

Unless you can reliably `ORDER BY` something in the table that happens to match the order of data in the input file. But even then you should be matching on the data, not ordinal position.

Comment: There is a bug in SSMS. I opened the csv - it had 23132 rows (1 header row). Post import select count(1) says 17304. So there must be a point at which SSMS times out or something. It also said it 'stopped' in the import wizard reporting. -but gave no reason.